# Extracting the original data based on filtering criteria

Tags: r

This is my transaction data:

```
id          from_id        to_id      amount    date_trx
<fctr>      <fctr>         <fctr>     <dbl>     <date>
0           7468           5695       700.0     2005-01-04
1           6213           9379       11832.0   2005-01-08
2           7517           8170       1000.0    2005-01-10
3           6143           9845       4276.0    2005-01-12
4           6254           9640       200.0     2005-01-14
5           6669           5815       200.0     2005-01-20
6           6934           8583       49752.0   2005-01-24
7           9240           8314       19961.0   2005-01-26
8           6374           8865       1000.0    2005-01-30
9           6143           6530       13.4      2005-01-31
...
```

I manipulated it as follows:

```
data %>% group_by(date_trx=floor_date(date_trx, "week"),from_id) %>%
   summarize(amount=sum(amount)) %>%
    filter(amount > 1000)
```

Here what I did is I wanted to sort the data per week so that I could see the total amount transacted by each account per week and then get the ones only above a certain value which is 1000 in my case.

And I got the following:

```
date_trx    from_id amount
<date>      <fctr>  <dbl>
2005-01-02  5773    7174.0      
2005-01-02  6213    12032.0     
2005-01-02  6375    3742.0      
2005-01-02  6510    5698.0      
2005-01-02  6727    5923.0      
2005-01-02  7047    1100.0      
2005-01-02  7207    1100.0      
2005-01-02  9440    1100.0      
2005-01-02  9493    4201.0      
2005-01-09  5997    5209.0
...
```

Now, I want to get the original data where it satisfices the filtering condition above. How can I do that? To make it more clear, lets take 5773 into account. We know that for 5773 total transaction amount within 2005-01-02 is 7174.0, so this amount is higher than the threshold 1000 so I keep this account. But after filtering it this way, I want to only extract the individual transactions which in total sum up to 7174.0.

Comment: If you need the original `filter`ed data, then don't `summarise` i.e. `data %>% group_by(date_trx_week =floor_date(date_trx, "week"),from_id) %>% filter(sum(amount) > 1000) %>% ungroup %>% select(-date_trx_week)`  It would be helpful if the expected output is showed for the input example

Comment: I guess the output yout got is based on the entire data.  Please show the expected output for the rows that you showed in input

Comment: Your solution gives me the output I wanted actually. Thank you @akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need to `summarise`, just `filter` after grouping by and then remove the temporary column created.  Note that many of the functions in `tidyverse` can do the computation on the fly (`sum(amount)`) without even creating a column

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
data %>% 
    group_by(date_trx_week =floor_date(date_trx, "week"),from_id) %>% 
    filter(sum(amount) > 1000) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-date_trx_week)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method.

1. Add `week_trx` as a `floor`ing of the date instead of replacing `date_trx`. Do it before summarizing, too, since we'll use this to join the data back onto the summary.
2. Renamed `sum_amount`, so that we can easily differentiate the original/individual `amount` with the summed amount. (Granted, we can easily differentiate them without this step, but you'd have names `amount.x` and `amount.y`, which are less intuitive to me.)

```r
dat <- mutate(dat, week_trx = lubridate::floor_date(date_trx, "week"))
datsumm <- dat %>%
  group_by(week_trx, from_id) %>%
  summarize(sum_amount = sum(amount)) %>%
  filter(sum_amount > 1000) %>%
  ungroup()
datsumm
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   week_trx   from_id sum_amount
#   <date>       <int>      <dbl>
# 1 2005-01-02    6213      11832
# 2 2005-01-09    6143       4276
# 3 2005-01-23    6934      49752
# 4 2005-01-23    9240      19961
left_join(datsumm, dat, by = c("week_trx", "from_id"))
# # A tibble: 4 x 7
#   week_trx   from_id sum_amount    id to_id amount date_trx  
#   <date>       <int>      <dbl> <int> <int>  <dbl> <date>    
# 1 2005-01-02    6213      11832     1  9379  11832 2005-01-08
# 2 2005-01-09    6143       4276     3  9845   4276 2005-01-12
# 3 2005-01-23    6934      49752     6  8583  49752 2005-01-24
# 4 2005-01-23    9240      19961     7  8314  19961 2005-01-26
```

In this sample, there are four rows in the summary and four rows in the rejoined table, but when there are more than one row per `from_id`, you'll get a more representative result. As a demonstration, I'll adjust several of the `from_id`s so that there is some commonality.

```r
set.seed(4)
dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(from_id = sample(head(from_id, 3), size = n(), replace = TRUE))
datsumm2 <- dat2 %>%
  group_by(week_trx, from_id) %>%
  summarize(sum_amount = sum(amount)) %>%
  filter(sum_amount > 1000) %>%
  ungroup()
datsumm2
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   week_trx   from_id sum_amount
#   <date>       <int>      <dbl>
# 1 2005-01-02    7468      11832
# 2 2005-01-09    7468       5276
# 3 2005-01-23    7517      69713
left_join(datsumm2, dat2, by = c("week_trx", "from_id"))
# # A tibble: 5 x 7
#   week_trx   from_id sum_amount    id to_id amount date_trx  
#   <date>       <int>      <dbl> <int> <int>  <dbl> <date>    
# 1 2005-01-02    7468      11832     1  9379  11832 2005-01-08
# 2 2005-01-09    7468       5276     2  8170   1000 2005-01-10
# 3 2005-01-09    7468       5276     3  9845   4276 2005-01-12
# 4 2005-01-23    7517      69713     6  8583  49752 2005-01-24
# 5 2005-01-23    7517      69713     7  8314  19961 2005-01-26
```

---

Data:

```r
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
id          from_id        to_id      amount    date_trx
0           7468           5695       700.0     2005-01-04
1           6213           9379       11832.0   2005-01-08
2           7517           8170       1000.0    2005-01-10
3           6143           9845       4276.0    2005-01-12
4           6254           9640       200.0     2005-01-14
5           6669           5815       200.0     2005-01-20
6           6934           8583       49752.0   2005-01-24
7           9240           8314       19961.0   2005-01-26
8           6374           8865       1000.0    2005-01-30
9           6143           6530       13.4      2005-01-31")
dat$date_trx <- as.Date(dat$date_trx)
```